# Unable to run Stunner Standalone Showcase (part from KIE Workbench)

Tags: intellij-idea, gwt, jbpm, kie-workbench

I'm trying to run the [stunner standalone showcase application](https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-wb-common/tree/master/kie-wb-common-stunner/kie-wb-common-stunner-showcase) which is part of the KIE Workbench and I'm following the steps provided [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-wb-common/tree/master/kie-wb-common-stunner).

I'm stuck at **Configure GWT Facets** step 3 here I should configure the GWT facet because there is no option called *Facets* under *Project Setting* in my menu.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15.06 with GWT-Platform (GWTP) IntelliJ IDEA Plugin v1.2.1 installed. I also have GWT v2.9.0 installed. OS is Windows.

I am new to IntelliJ and GWT. Am I doing something wrong or is there something wrong with the instructions/code?

Comment: The GWT Plugin is not part of the IntelliJ Community Edition. So, in case you are using the Community edition you are not able to set the facet.

Comment: Well yes, I am using the Community Edition so this seems to be the problem.
I did not expect an open-source project to write their documentation tailored to a commercial version of an IDE...

Many thanks for pointing out the issue!

Comment: GWT does not require IntelliJ Ultimate. You can run it using Maven in the Community edition. No need for the GWT plugin.